# Are all undead evil?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, alignment

Based on the [creature type undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Undead), are they innately evil? The creature type listing for them does not list it, but its mentioned in the things that everyone knows about the undead. But does that mean that each one actually has an evil alignment or is that section just flavor text?

Comment: Also heavily related, though not quite a duplicate: [Can a good cleric use necromancy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31112/4563) Finally note that, even if this *weren’t* a duplicate, this question would arguably be [the off-topic kind of alignment question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357/4563).

Comment: @KRyan Im actually asking partly to prepare for another question.

Comment: Be sure to review the rules on alignment topicality.