# Can you be afraid if you're dead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions, character-death, immunities, fear

At 7th level, a Dread becomes [immune to fear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/dread#TOC-Immersed-in-Fear-Su-). The class feature says the following:

> At 7th level, the dread gains immunity to fear (psionic or otherwise). This ability functions whether the dread is conscious or unconscious, but not when she is dead.

That's pretty cool and all, but what's the point of this being inactive when the Dread is dead?

Is there anything that can make you afraid when you're dead? Is there any situation wherein it would be useful to subject a dead creature to fear, given that they're... well... dead?

(I'm presuming that if you were fearing their *ghost* or something, the ghost would be *undead* and technically alive, not dead, and thus its immunity to fear would be fully operational.)

Comment: Relevant: [Can a Good-aligned 'Necromancer' cast the Animate Objects spell on a bunch of corpses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36105/1421)

Comment: I don't have the Pathfinder rules for petitioners handy. Does anyone know if they lose class features upon death?

Comment: @GMJoe http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/petitioner-cr-1 :)

Comment: Relevant: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37131/4563 Note how the game *doesn’t really define what being dead means in terms of abilities and conditions.*

Comment: Well... if the Dread is ALL dead, there's nothing you can do.  However, your friend is only MOSTLY dead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The description of the [*dead* condition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Dead) has the following:

> The character's hit points are reduced to a negative amount equal to
>   his Constitution score, his Constitution drops to 0, or he is killed
>   outright by a spell or effect. **The character's soul leaves his body.**

(Emphasis mine.)

The soul then can be affected by various things, like the [Soul Bind spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/soul-bind), etc. - not to mention that there's a whole afterlife waiting for them where this may matter. ([Petitioners](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/petitioner-cr-1) do "lose all special qualities, along with all abilities granted by class levels", but the RAW sometimes might emphasize this and that by repetition, for example.)