# Is there a psionic power that can cure the victim of decerebrate?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

There's a 7th level save-or-die psionic power called [*decerebrate*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/decerebrate.htm) that, in short, removes a part of the victim's brain stem, turning the victim into a limpy vegetable, and, if the victim's not cured in 1d4 days, the victim perishes.

Some effects *can* cure this condition (namely, the spell [*greater restoration*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/restorationGreater.htm) or another similar 7th-level or higher curative effect), but I can't find a good **psionic** way to do so. There's the costly way of using [*bend reality*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/bendReality.htm) or [*reality revision*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/realityRevision.htm) (i.e. psionic *limited wish* or *wish*, respectively) or decapitating the victim then manifesting [*restore extremity*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/restoreExtremity.htm) followed by [*psionic revivify*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/psionicRevivify.htm), but is there a cheaper or less extreme psionic way to help a buddy who's been the victim of the power *decerebrate*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ooookay, so here's what I've got:*

While there is no external non-exclusive psionic power of 7+ level that can cure the victim of Decerebrate, there is one internal power that does what we need: [True Metabolism](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/trueMetabolism.htm). The key is to make this power think that someone else is you. There are SEVERAL ways to make it work:

- If you're an Egoist with Life
  Mantle, your True Metabolism power can be augmented for 5 additional
  PP to affect a creature touched. With Torc of Power Preservation,
  Mantle special ablity and Earth Power, the lowest level you can do
  this trick is 17, which is not that bad
- The [Mind Switch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/mindSwitch.htm), 6th level power from Telepath class list is a little bit pricey (100 xp), but still much cheaper than Revivify (200 xp +100 xp per round of the victim being
  dead) or Bend Reality (300+ xp). Since manifesting powers is a purely mental action, the lack of any sensory feedback won't get in the way of manifesting. Doable from 15th level
- The [Fusion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fusion.htm), 8th level
  power from Egoist class list. This one is a little murky since it's
  not clear whenether the fusioned character HAS missing parts of his
  brain to regrow, so this one somewhat depends on DM. If manifesting
  True Metabolism after the Fusion lets you regrow the missing brain
  stem of the victim, it'll cost you just 50 xp for the Fusion power.
  Achieveable from 15th level

Or, if you're a Telepath (or an epic level Psion with Epic Manifesting and Expanded Knowledge):

- Your 9th level power [Psychic Chirurgery](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/psychicChirurgery.htm) can negate any
  instantaneous or permanent effect caused by a psychic power
  (including Decerebrate), which is nice... But isn't applicable to
  anyone else pre-epic. Still, Telepaths can do this from 17th level

Besides that... I'm not really sure there is anything else. Most of the time, it would be easier to just Bend Reality to achieve this.

Comment: Mind Switch only lasts for 10 minutes/level. What you want is [True Mind Switch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/mindSwitchTrue.htm).

Comment: There is no need to switch minds for THAT long - True Metabolism has the manifesting time of 1 round, and duration of 1 minute/level. All you have to do is just manifest it and concentrate on regrowing the brain stem. Through yeah, you could also trade bodies with your big-buffy-fighter-buddy so that he's alive again while you're both alive and strong, mentally and physically 8)

Comment: Och, and let's not forget that True Mind Switch is a little bit TOO expensive (10 000 xp), while the question was about the ways to psionically cure this condition cheaply

Comment: My bad. I misread the question as "how do I cure decerebrate in myself".

Answer (score 2):

The wizard spell Temporal Stasis can keep the person alive long enough for you to get to someone who has access to greater restoration, but reality revision or bend reality are probably your best bet at restoring someone who has been targeted by Decerebrate.

Your suggestion of restore extremity and psionic revivify isn't bad, if it can be attempted fast enough that the cost for revivify isn't too enormous. You can also circumvent decerebrate by using Time regression to replay the previous round, hoping that he makes the save in the second round, but that's a big *if*. (If he has a good modifier and he just rolled bad the first time, it may be worth a try)

The best power for removing a psionic effect without paying an EXP cost is [Psychic Chirurgery](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/psychicChirurgery.htm) though, if you have the power this one is a great boon, Removes the effects of Microcosm, decerebrate, any of the psionic domination effects, you name it.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, but they are oddly specific methods...

There are other options not listed in any of the other answers for this question.

**Option 1**

- Use a method to remove the mind/soul from the body, say for example, the 5th level power *Steal Steel*, a dragon created power which allows one to possess metal edged weapons. (Wyrms of the North, Eldensar - WotC web article, also Dragon #237)
- Allow your body to die.
- Your body is now an object (no CHA and/or no WIS scores = object per SRD)‡‡.
- Use *Psionic Make Whole* (Secrets of Sarlona, p133.) Unlike the spell *Mending* which it otherwise resembles, the target is not limited by weight, but rather uses a cubic foot per level metric, which means it can target a corpse if you are high enough level, or bend the corpse into amusing pretzel shapes before the fix (highly effective for practical jokes or grudges). Note that it can restore multiple breaks, of which *Decerebrate* makes two.
- Use *Psionic Revivify*. Better yet, have two people time it so that both powers are manifested in the same round with different initiative... saves on effective cost of the revivify.

**Option 2**

- Have a very trusting and understanding friend kill you, precisely enough to bring you to exactly -10 hp. (This precision is to minimize the subsequently required saving throw.)
- Use *Fiery Discorporation*, a fifth level Kineticist power, to cheat death.

Both of these methods kicks in at lower level than any of the other answers provided at the time of this answer's posting.

> ‡‡: Please note, the interpretation that "corpse=object" is subject to much controversy, with strong arguments on both the 'yes' and 'no' sides. This subject tends to generate lots of comments and rules bickering. Check with your GM(s) for which ruling applies to you.

Comment: RE: "Your body is now an object (no CHA and/or no WIS scores = object per SRD)." This is more controversial than it might initially appear. While the *FAQ* makes corpses objects, nothing in the rules says death causes ability score drain or causes a creature to have nonabilities.

Comment: I recall a similar discussion in that possessing a clone question I posted. I see. A shame they left that so ambiguous. Even the animated object to corpse question didn't clarify?

Comment: @KRyan and I *still* disagree, but [I made the strongest case I could](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36105/8610). *I* think corpses-into-objects is a one-way ticket to crazy town, but other folks think it's totally legit to put a permanent *symbol of death* or *teleportation circle* on the dead fighter's corpse-that's-now-an-object then cast *true resurrection* on him. Whatever. `;-)` All I'm *really* saying is that it might be worth citing the *FAQ* directly in your answer (and all that *that* entails) as the printed rules are, to say the least, vague.

Comment: *Trap the Soul*, *Soul Bind*, and *Magic Jar establish that "soul" and "life force" are used interchangeably. *Speak with Dead* establishes that a corpse does not have a soul. Complete Divine, section 6, "What happens when you die" also establishes that a soul lingers only shortly near a corpse and/or place of death before departing the Prime and appearing on an Outer Plane, unless they become a ghost or undead, ie: corpse has no soul. *Magic Jar* and *Mind Switch* establish that INT, WIS, and CHA are part of the soul and go with it. Ergo, a corpse, not having a soul, is in fact, an object. ^^

Comment: Having said all that, I agree with you in that it does cause some crazy odd side effects that should be eyeballed carefully. I think a simple way to address this is to rule a corpse an object, update the dead condition to reflect that, but also mention that coming back to life in any way invalidates any ongoing effects that require an object as a target or in order to function.

Comment: Man, I just can't get behind the specific cases of *magic jar* and *mind switch* applying generally. Further, establishing *how long* the soul lingers then becomes a thing, since it's only *after* its departure (by this reading) that a corpse becomes an object, and, specifically, *soul bind* makes how long a soul lingers—not kidding here—dependent upon the *caster level* of the spell [*soul bind*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/soulBind.htm) spell! (Seriously, though, all you have to do for my upvote is an edit saying it's controversial, and I'm on board.)