# What happens to a mythic creatures mythic pool who is resurrected on a different day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-death, mythic-adventures, resurrection

Mythic power is a much newer aspect of the game than being killed and resurrected. Those spells were never updated with respect to the new character feature.

So the question is, at what level is a mythic characters pool when they are killed and brought back to life on a different day?

Lets take a 3rd tier mythic character with no increases to the number of mythic power they have. They have 3+2*3=9 uses a day. This character used 4 during the day they died, so they had 5 remaining when they died. The next day the cleric has the right spell to bring them back to life, but what total is the mythic pool at? Is it 5 or back to full at 9?

Mythic power recharges differently than all other point pools.

[Mythic Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes#TOC-Mythic-Power-Su-)

> Mythic characters can draw upon a wellspring of power to accomplish amazing deeds and cheat fate. This power is used by a number of different abilities. **Each day**, you can expend an amount of mythic power equal to 3 plus double your mythic tier (5/day at 1st tier, 7/day at 2nd, etc.). This amount is your maximum amount of mythic power. If an ability allows you to regain uses of your mythic power, you can never have more than this amount.

[Monk's Ki Pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Ki-Pool-Su-)

> The ki pool is replenished each morning after 8 hours of rest or meditation; these hours do not need to be consecutive.

[Magus Arcane Pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Arcane-Pool-Su-)

> The pool refreshes once per day when the magus prepares his spells.

[Arcanist Reservoir](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist#TOC-Arcane-Reservoir-Su-)

> Each day, when preparing spells, the arcanist's arcane reservoir fills with raw magical energy, gaining a number of points equal to 3 + 1/2 her arcanist level. Any points she had from the previous day are lost.

So the other pools all have specific triggers on how they refill, but mythic just seems to be each day you have a free pool, no action required. So I feel that our character who has returned to life should now have a full mythic pool in which to draw power from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the mythic creature is brought back from the dead on a day after the day it died, it can expend its daily supply of [mythic power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes#TOC-Mythic-Power-Su-) normally, no matter how much mythic power it had expended on the day it died. Each day simply yields a new supply of mythic power.

Unlike, for example, a monk's [*ki* pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Ki-Pool-Su-) or a magus's [arcane pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Arcane-Pool-Su-), the mythic creature needn't actually *do* anything to regain its mythic power. Instead, for a mythic creature to be able to once more employ fully its mythic power only time must pass,… and—despite its best efforts and no matter its degree of self-absorption—, time passes while it's dead.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, which means my mythic battery system will work. Every time we defeat a mythic foe I will end up carting around their corpse and cast steal power, because the dead are still creatures and thus valid targets, and as you just mentioned, their mythic pool refills without any action on their part.

Comment: @Fering Although *this* GM is of the opinion that dead creatures remain creatures at heart, *your* GM may have the opposite opinion and rule that the dead are objects or even something impossibly in between. Ask first, and steel yourself for disappointment.

Comment: All the resurrection spells targets say "dead creature" which means that the dead are both objects and creatures. I also suspect that there's no way this is going to be allowed to work, and if it does good bye good alignment.

Comment: @Fering Hence making them something impossibly in between. Anyway, like I said, I'm *totally* on your side here ([with the downvotes to prove it!](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36113/8610)), but expect your GM to opine differently.