# Can I burn my enemies to ashes with fire spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, damage-types

People die and bodies burn to ashes when you burn them. I don't want to see my enemies corpses burning, I want to see them turned to ashes immediately without resorting to disintegrate and similar spells, only instantaneous fire magic like *Fireball*, *Firebrand* or *Meteor Swarm*.

How much fire damage do I need to cause with my fire spells to make an alive enemy burn to ashes in an instant?

Is killing enough (reducing to -10 hp)? I suppose it isn't. Then reduce to -30 hp? More? Less?

Comment: I think you may be underestimating how hard it is to burn someone to ashes. In real life, cremation typically takes several hours.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I think you're underestimating _magic_.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general rule like “if you reduce a foe to −30 hp with fire damage, their body burns to ash.” There is no feat with that as a benefit, no class that offers anything of the sort.

There **might** be spells that do something like that, but I don’t know of any. Considering that *disintegrate* is a classic, high-level, almost-unique spell, I find it somewhat unlikely that anything similar is available at a lower level. Literally the only other spell I can find that disintegrates creatures is *sphere of ultimate destruction*, a 9th-level spell from *Spell Compendium* that basically functions like a reusable (1/round for 1 round/level) *disintegrate*. And considering that *Races of the Wild* includes a 4th-level spell, *dust to dust*, that takes a standard action to disintegrate a *corpse*, this feature seems to be valued rather highly by Wizards of the Coast. It does not appear that they want you to be able to disintegrate creatures easily—no area effects, no multiple-target effects until you get to the 9th-level *sphere of ultimate destruction* and even that takes multiple rounds to target multiple creatures, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If corpses are objects, not creatures, [which is unclear](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36113/14848), then they [have hardness and hit points](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm).  You would need to do enough fire damage to destroy said object and for the GM not to rule that fire is incapable of harming that sort of object. Note that fire damage typically deals half damage against objects, and there are no rules to determine hardness nor hp of a corpse.  You should note that nothing indicates 'extra' damage done to a creature will apply to the corpse they leave behind-- you very probably need to hit a target with at least two instances of damge and if you want to do this with a single spell that spell needs to affect both creatures and objects.

If corpses are creatures, not objects, then no amount of damage will cause them to stop existing. In fact, if you rule that corpses are still creatures then, just like you can't cut the arm off a living monster in a fight, you can't cut the arm off a dead monster or otherwise dismember a corpse.  This is weird and buggy and a reason to *not* rule that dead creatures' corpses are creatures, but in this version of events you need an effect that specifically can destroy a corpse to do so.

Comment: Note that, for *dust to dust* to work, a corpse must be a creature. Otherwise it “deals damage” to a corpse, but does not disintegrate it. Maybe evidence, probably not really.

Comment: @KRyan I think HeyICanChan's linked answer does a better job of being a thorough overview of that whole deal.  This answer is trying to point out that the real ambiguity here comes from corpses being weird and that however your group answers *those* questions will make this question pretty straightforward.

Comment: Sure, just food for thought since I had the spell description open.

Comment: Any problem creatures being both 'creatures' and 'objects'? Corpses being 'dead creatures' and 'objects'? I.e. are there cases when something shouldn't be an object? Also you pretty much can dismember a creature (say, a helpless one). It is during round-by-round encounter where you typically can't.

Comment: @annoyingimp If they are objects you can use the object rule to destroy them.  Creature and object is object. Neither creature nor object is ???

Comment: @annoyingimp the binary I used is for parallelism.  I think it makes the answer more easily readible and , while technically wrong, it's pretty close to right and it's not *misleading*, it just doesn't talk about some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't any rule for that, so I suppose that it is a DM's choice. I wouldn't allow a PC to always turn his enemies into ashes, but I could make that happen in case of critical rolls or in case of very huge fire damages.
Also consider that burning your enemies into ashes could be a disadvantage: what about if the guy you have just destroyed was carrying the important message you had to bring to the king or something like that?