# Where can I find player available rituals for creating undead?

Tags: dnd-4e, undead, rituals, books, necromancy

I like to DM D&D 4e and recently acquired *Open Grave*, a rules supplement on undead. But there are no rituals for creating combat-capable undead (they are all listed as "non-combatants"). Is there a different book with a ritual that creates combat-capable undead, or can my players not create combat-capable undead?

Comment: 4e has stricter expectations of creatures who will engage in combat, so there *may* be a reasonably-accepted definition of “combat-capable,” but typically we expect questions here to *define* what it means to be capable engaging in combat. Our 4e experts may even decide to put this question on Hold until you provide a definition (I leave this to them since I do not know 4e well enough). A question on Hold cannot receive answers until it is edited and reopened. For an introduction to the site, and advice on how to write good questions, I recommend the [Tour].

Comment: @KRyan In this case is does simply mean "capable". The few rituals that create undead in *Open Grave* explicitly say they're non-combatants and list no combat stats.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Aha, that would do it! (we really must get a flag for obsolete that allows you to acknowledge the comment)

Comment: Related question about making a necromancer PC: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12796/can-a-necromancer-be-made-in-4e

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no player-available rituals to do this in any supplement that I know of, even the Book of Vile Darkness.

However, as for your second question (Or can my players not create combat-capable undead), the Shadow Done Right 4th Edition supplements (http://shadow4e.wikidot.com/) contain a Necromancer class and at least one ritual concerning raising the undead.

Answer (score 0):

Open grave was designed more as a GM expansion than a player expansion.  Summoning extra creatures for PC to use has (and will likely always be) a source of contention.  Rather than feed the fires of the "overpowered" clan the designers simply sidestepped the issue.  If you look at RAW than nope- no can do, they are essentially undead pack mules.  That doesn't mean you can't come up with a ritual and cost and add it, but I would almost certainly turn the request for an undead sword sponge into another opportunity for Murphy to rear his undead grinning skull...

E.G.

> GM: Well, that was a tough battle, but it looks like with Zombie Steve's help, you have defeated the bandits.
>
> Zanzibar the Necromancer: Fear the wrath of Zanzibar!
>
> GM: Can I have Steve's character sheet: he's gained a level.
>
> Player: Sure! Hey, can I pick his skills, I'd like him to have Unstoppable.
>
> GM: Fantastic! Roll 2d6, then everyone roll a d20.
>
> Player: Uh, sure. What's the d20 for?
>
> GM: It seems that with power comes responsibility: Steve has decided that since he's taking most of the risk, he really doesn't need the middle man anymore. You also notice that Steve is carrying a longsword.
>
> Player: Zombies don't use weapons!
>
> GM: Use them in battle enough and it looks like they are not completely untrainable, if you and the group survive think of the missives you'll write.